# Expressions in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

Which places in a conventional `SELECT` statement allow for expressions? The backend doesn't matter, I mean more from a conceptual (iso?) standpoint.

For example, in doing some basic testing (using mysql8, but again, I'm not concerned about a particular backend) it seems it's allowed everywhere except in the `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` place:

```
with tbl (num, str) as (
    select 1, 'a'
) 
SELECT
    (select num from tbl limit 1) select_expr -- select expression
FROM
    (select * from tbl limit 1) table_expr -- table expression
WHERE
    (select null from tbl)
    or 1 = (select num from tbl)
    or (select num from tbl) = (select num from tbl) -- filter expressions, can be lhs or rhs or single subselect
GROUP BY
    num, (select num from tbl) -- aggregate expression
HAVING
    (select num from tbl limit 1)
ORDER BY
    (select num from tbl limit 1)
LIMIT
    (select num from tbl limit 1) -- invalid
OFFSET
    (select num from tbl limit 1) -- invalid
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your reputation should know how to tag questions.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: yes, why not? In SELECT and WHERE it is called subquery. In the FROM it is called inline view. LIMIT is my sql and OFFSET is Sql Server. Both have specific syntax. GROUP BY i don't remember. I think, you can do in ORDER BY. BUt I wouldn't do it in GB and OB because this will sink performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a *scalar subquery* is allowed anywhere a constant value is allowed -- `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, for instance.

A *scalar subquery* is a subquery that returns at most one row and one value (i.e. one expression or column in general).

Whether they are allowed as `GROUP BY` keys might depend on the database.  But then again, "constant" values are not necessarily supported as `GROUP BY` keys.

`LIMIT` is not a standard SQL clause.  How it behaves depends entirely on the database defining it.  The equivalent in standard SQL is `FETCH`; I believe it requires actual constants, but different databases may treat it differently.

Comment: and then one last question: in the `FROM <table_expression>` the table_expression can be either a scalar or non-scalar subquery (is it more correct to say 'any table expression or table name'?)

Comment: @David542 . . . It can be any subquery -- and that is a superset of subqueries that have one column (in most databases) and at most one row.  The later are scalar subqueries when used in a scalar context.

Comment: thanks, finally, does the lhs of the `WHERE` clause ever restrict it in various dbs? For example `<field> <op> <expr>` is allowed but `<expr1> <op> <expr2>` is not allowed?

Comment: @David542 . . . I cannot think of any cases where a binary operator would limit an operand to a literal value.  There are some cases with functions, such as `MATCH()`in MySQL that require some arguments to be constant values, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is helpful:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
> by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
> which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
> exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Comment: thanks, is that how it is in other dbs too, or just mysql?

Comment: LIMIT is non-standard syntax. It's supported by only MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite as far as I know. SQLite allows an expression if it evaluates to an integer. I'm not sure about PostgreSQL. The documentation sort of mentions that the count can be an expression, but it doesn't explicitly say so.

Comment: I see. What does Oracle do for the Limit?

Comment: Oracle has multiple solutions: https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/oracle/31-new-pagination-method-in-oracle-12c-offset-fetch.